# How to remove mysql database storing error?

Tags: java, mysql, database, exception, error-handling

This is my code using java as front end and backend as mysql, the exception is again and again even after making lot of changes.

```
else if(s1.equals("Save")){

            try
            {
        
            if(flag==1)
            {       
                rs1.insertRow();
            }
            int id1=Integer.parseInt(tmid.getText());
            
            String d=tdate.getText();
            
            String ab=tabal.getText();
            int amt=Integer.parseInt(tamt.getText());
            String t1=ttt.getText()+":"+ttt2.getText();
            String l=tlt.getText()+":"+tlt1.getText();
            String o=tot.getText()+":"+tot1.getText();
            
            rs1.updateString(2,d);
            rs1.updateString(3,ab);
            rs1.updateString(4,t1);
            rs1.updateString(5,l);
            rs1.updateString(6,o);
            rs1.updateInt(7,amt);
            rs1.updateInt(8,id1);
            
            
            //System.out.println(rs3.getString(1));
            System.out.println("JAYASHRI");
                 
            if(flag==1)
            {
                
                rs1.moveToInsertRow();
            
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Adding New Record Successfully!!","Add New Record",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
                
    }else if(s1.equals("Save")){
            try
            {
        
            if(flag==1)
            {       
                rs1.insertRow();
            }
            int id1=Integer.parseInt(tmid.getText());
            
            String d=tdate.getText();
            
            String ab=tabal.getText();
            int amt=Integer.parseInt(tamt.getText());
            String t1=ttt.getText()+":"+ttt2.getText();
            String l=tlt.getText()+":"+tlt1.getText();
            String o=tot.getText()+":"+tot1.getText();
            
            rs1.updateString(2,d);
            rs1.updateString(3,ab);
            rs1.updateString(4,t1);
            rs1.updateString(5,l);
            rs1.updateString(6,o);
            rs1.updateInt(7,amt);
            rs1.updateInt(8,id1);
            
            
            //System.out.println(rs3.getString(1));
            System.out.println("JAYASHRI");
                 
            if(flag==1)
            {
                
                rs1.moveToInsertRow();
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Adding New Record Successfully!!","Add New Record",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
                
    }
```

[example image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVopu.png), I cant remove the database storing error.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what do u want actually

Comment: Something that makes it clear where the error is, for starters. Maybe something that's correctly formatted. A stack trace instead of a popup that displays an error with a string that you generate. Anyway, it's all perfectly explained in the link I gave you.